# Oculta y mostrar Texbox c#

Tags: c#

Una consulta hay alguna manera de ocultar y mostrar una caja de texto utilizando una combinación de teclas. Por ejemplo que se muestre con `Ctrl+Q`  y se vuelva ocultar con la misma combinación.

Comment: Por supuesto que si!

Comment: POn lo que has intentado para que se te pueda ayudar

Comment: con la propiedad visible true o false.... lo colocas en un evento de las teclas que quieras y listo

Answer (score 1):

Existe una forma sin ninguna librería. Tomando en cuenta que es una aplicación de escritorio tengo el siguiente ejemplo.
Primero hay que setear en true la propiedad KeyPreview:

[image: Propiedad formulario]

Basicamente la propiedad KeyPreview indica si el formulario recibirá eventos clave antes de que el evento se pase al control que tiene el foco.
(Acá esta explicado junto con los eventos mencionados: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

Luego en los eventos del formulario deberías crear el evento KeyUp o para KeyDown (esto es a gusto) y te quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
    //Con evento KeyUp
    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Q)))
        {
            txtNombre.Visible = !txtNombre.Visible;
        }
    }

    //Con evento KeyDown

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyData == (Keys.Control |Keys.Q)))
        {
            txtNombre.Visible = !txtNombre.Visible;
        }
    }
```

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda. Saludos!!

Comment: Buena respuesta. Podrías mejorarla explicando por qué debe usar `KeyPreview`. Y te dejo otra opción para alternar el valor de `Visible`: `txtNombre.Visible = !txtNombre.Visible;`. Con eso conviertes las 4 líneas del if-else en una sola.

Comment: Pero esto.. se va a ejecutar cuando presione las teclas y cuando las suelte.. o sea.. no lo va a hacer.. no?.. y toma en cuenta lo que dijo mateo.. se hace en una sola linea ;)

Comment: Hola chicos, muchas gracias por tomarse su tiempo en corregirme, ahí edite la respuesta. Saludos!